# Group by week, how to get empty weeks?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have the following code, which groups some events (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) in weeks which are displayed as for example "Y:2010 - Week: 50".

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, 'Y:%X - Week:%V') AS regweek, COUNT(*) as number
```

it works good, but I would like to return all weeks, even if the ones in which no event is placed.

If no event is registered in the third week, at the moment I get:

```
week 1: 10
week 2: 1
week 4: 2
```

I would like to get:

```
week 1: 10
week 2: 1
week 3: 0
week 4: 2
```

Comment: You want *all* weeks since when? The beginning of time?

Comment: All weeks from the when the first event happened or maybe the last N months would be OK as too. It should just be a "continuous" period of time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL cannot return rows that don't exist in some table.  To get the effect you want, you will need a table Weeks (WeekNo INT) with one row per possible week of the year (which, IIRC, is either 53 or 54 possible weeks, depending on how you count).

Then, JOIN this table to your regular results with an OUTER JOIN to get the extra weeks added in.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, 'Y:%X - Week:%V') AS regweek, COUNT(date) as number 
    FROM YourTable RIGHT OUTER JOIN Weeks ON WEEK(YourTable.date) = Weeks.WeekNo
```

[Update]: Note the user of COUNT(date) rather than COUNT(*).  SQL will not include NULL values in the date column when adding up the COUNT.  Since the missing weeks will not have any dates in them, this will correctly give you 0 events for those weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am trying to follow this way, but the right join will return number = 1 for a specific week even if there was no event in that week, right?

Comment: You must change COUNT(*) to COUNT(date).  Since date will be NULL for the "missing" weeks, it won't be included in the count.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: wonderful! If I am not wrong, your answer also needs a "group by Weeks.WeekNo" in order to work properly

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I just took your SQL fragment from the original question and added the JOIN, you will still have to apply the filtering, grouping, and ordering you were using before (but using WeekNo instead of regweek, of course).

Answer (score 1):

At the end I decided to solve the issue as follow, creating a temporary table for the weeks and using the code that was found out in the answer here above.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weeks (
         id INT
       );
INSERT INTO weeks (id) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40), (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50), (51), (52), (53), (54);
SELECT 
w.id, COUNT(c.issuedate) as numberPerWeek
FROM tableName c RIGHT OUTER JOIN weeks w ON WEEK(c.issuedate) = w.id group by w.id;
```

Comment: You're actually creating a temporary numbers table this way to produce your result :-) They're a good general technique, well worth reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of problem for which numbers/tally tables are made - just a simple table that counts from 0 to whatever. They're useful in general, I'd always recommend adding them to your database.

With this you can relatively easily generate a list of weeks on the fly without needing a specific precalculated table of weeks (so you don't need either a huge table or to worry about running out of weeks), then left join that against your list of appointments to show all weeks with an appointment in them.

For a quick start:

```
declare @min    datetime
set     @min    ='2010-01-01'

select
    dateadd(wk, number, @min) as weekDate
from
    numbers
where
    number between 0 and datediff(wk,@min,getdate())
```

with