# Oracle SQL: How to show empty weeks / weeks without data?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805560/group-by-week-how-to-get-empty-weeks), but my dataset has an additional column with many IDs. Each ID has a dataset that goes back by a constant timeframe, and some of the weeks may be missing data - I would like to fill in values for missing weeks.

For example, I want this:

```
ID      WEEKEND_DAY     VALUE
A00     2012-01-01      1
A00     2012-01-08      7
B00     2012-01-08      4
B00     2012-01-15      3
```

to expand to this:

```
ID      WEEKEND_DAY     VALUE
A00     2012-01-01      1
A00     2012-01-08      7
A00     2012-01-15      0
B00     2012-01-01      0
B00     2012-01-08      4
B00     2012-01-15      3
```

where I already have a known range of WEEKEND_DAYs (in the above case, weekly from 2012-01-01 to 2012-01-15) that I want to fill in. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Would you want a missing week, even if there was nothing in the table for that week at all?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes, I do - though with my dataset, theoretically it shouldn't happen.

Comment: In postgres there's function called generate_series that can be used to generate a control table with all the weeks.  I didn't look into this in detail but may be of help... http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/82/generate_series-an-oracle-implementation-in-light-of-sql-design-patterns/

Comment: @samyi Getting the series of weeks isn't a problem (I'm using SELECT rownum FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= n) - the problem is joining it to the existing data table. I can't run a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the series of weeks, because I need to fill in the ID column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [partitioned outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2196190):

```
select data.id, weeks.weekend_day, nvl(value, 0) value
from
(
    select date '2012-01-01' weekend_day from dual union all
    select date '2012-01-08' weekend_day from dual union all
    select date '2012-01-15' weekend_day from dual
) weeks
left join
(
    select 'A00' id, date '2012-01-01' weekend_day, 1 value from dual union all
    select 'A00' id, date '2012-01-08' weekend_day, 7 value from dual union all
    select 'B00' id, date '2012-01-08' weekend_day, 4 value from dual union all
    select 'B00' id, date '2012-01-15' weekend_day, 3 value from dual
) data
    partition by (data.id)
    on weeks.weekend_day = data.weekend_day
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just need each `ID` to be present for each possible week, this is decently simple.

First, I recommend a 'Calendar table' if you don't have one already.  This should include a column for the 'end' of the week (or at least, which day-of-week you want selected).  This can of course be generated dynamically with recursive CTEs, but a permanent one is useful regardless.

Given your original table:

```
WITH id_by_date (id, weekend) as (
                 SELECT a.id, b.actualDate
                 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id
                       FROM original) a  -- or use a table that only has ids
                 CROSS JOIN (SELECT actualDate
                             FROM calendar
                             WHERE isWeekend = '1') b) -- or dayOfWeek = 7
SELECT a.id, a.weekend, COALESCE(b.value, 0)
FROM id_by_date a
LEFT JOIN original b
ON b.id = a.id
AND b.weekend_day = a.weekend
ORDER BY a.id, a.weekend
```

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: @jonearles: Perhaps, not Oracle versions support this syntax, so you may be right. This *should* work in the latest version, though, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to DB2 (and I'm away from my instance).  Although I thought this was (fairly) standard syntax.

Comment: I couldn't understand what particular issues others found with it, but now I see them. For one thing, they are *all* trivial. All but one are related to `as` after tables and subselects: Oracle just doesn't like it there, so not `original as b` but simply `original b`, not `... from (select ...) as a` but just `... from (select ...) a` etc. And one other issue is an incorrect placement of a closing bracket: `where isWeekend = '1')) as b` should be `where is Weekend = '1') b)` (i.e. the alias should be moved to the position before the preceding bracket).

Comment: @AndriyM - Ah, thanks for pointing out the problem with `as`.  The misplacement of the alias inside the CTE was my own fault, though.