# show all rows when count return null using 1 table

Tags: sql, oracle

so i have a table screening:

```
Name                                      Null?      Type
--------------------------------------- --------  -------------

 SCREENINGNO                             NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(8)

 CINEMANO                                           VARCHAR2(8)

 MOVIENO                                            VARCHAR2(8)

 SUPERVISORNO                                       VARCHAR2(8)

 CAMERAOPNO                                         VARCHAR2(8)

 HOURSTART                                          NUMBER(38)

 SCREENINGDATE                                      DATE
```

the question is "Show the number of screenings that were scheduled for each month of 2015."

i've tried:

```
SELECT to_char(s1.screeningdate, 'mm') AS month
    ,count(s2.screeningno) AS number_of_times_screened
FROM screening s1
    ,screening s2
WHERE s1.movieno(+) = s2.movieno
    AND to_char(s1.screeningdate, 'yy') = '15'
GROUP BY to_char(s1.screeningdate, 'mm')
ORDER BY to_char(s1.screeningdate, 'mm');
```

it returned:

```
MO            NUMBER_OF_TIMES_SCREENED
--            ------------------------ 
01                       22

02                       31

03                       24

04                       32

05                       26

06                       37

07                       15

08                       15

10                       10

11                        5

12                        8
```

11 rows selected.

it only returns 11 rows, i need it to show the september as well. Can someone help?

Comment: You may want to provide sample data if you want any help. Also, check to see if you have any data for the month of September in your table.

Comment: Use a partition outer join, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254121/oracle-sql-how-to-show-empty-weeks-weeks-without-data/11256647#11256647. It's designed specifically for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use the `dual` psedotable with a `connect by level` clause to generate all the numbers between 1 and 12, and join that on the count of screenings:

```
SELECT    d.month, cnt
FROM      (SELECT     LPAD(LEVEL, 2, '0') AS month
           FROM       dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   TO_CHAR(screeningdate, 'mm') AS month, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     screeninginfo
           WHERE    TO_CHAR(screeningdate, 'yy') = '15'
           GROUP BY TO_CHAR(screeningdate, 'mm')) s ON d.month = s.month
ORDER BY  1 ASC
```

Comment: Looks great. A little adjustment may be needed to the join condition for single digit months.  As an example, for the month of January, the join condition will try to join `'1'` to `'01'`.

Comment: @sstan good catch, thanks - I've edited my answer to use `lpad` instead of a naive `to_char` to solve this issue.