# Reduce cost of oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I use following query to see an overview of all my statements and payments, grouped by week of year:

```
WITH FILTERED_BALANCES AS
(
    SELECT FACT_AS_BALANCE.* 
    FROM FACT_AS_BALANCE 
      JOIN DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS ON FACT_AS_BALANCE.BALANCE_TYPE_ID = DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS.ID 
    WHERE DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS.TRANSACTION_INTRADAY_FLAG = 'N'
      AND DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS.BALANCE_CLOSING_FLAG = 'Y'
)
SELECT DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, DD.CAL_YEAR, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT FPP.ID),0) AS PAYMENTS, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.ACCOUNT_STATEMENT_ID),0) AS STATEMENTS
FROM FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
  FULL OUTER JOIN FILTERED_BALANCES FAB ON FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID = FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID
  JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID OR FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID = DD.ID 
GROUP BY DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

This gives following output:

[image: Example of output]

This works but I have a serious performance leak because I use a full outer join in my query. The explain plan of Oracle SQL developer can you find underneath:
[image]

The question is to reduce the cost of this query. I tried to split up payments and statements but I have a logical problem. When I have payments in 1 week, but no statements, the statements result table doesn't have an entry for the week where they were no statements.

How to fix this issue with a better performance?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  There may be better ways to express your logic.

Comment: This might help to fix the empty weeks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805560/group-by-week-how-to-get-empty-weeks

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to help you without knowing your DB structure and having sample data. Please provide us more information.

Replace your full table select in the WITH clause by just using the columns you need.
Index them.

```
WITH FILTERED_BALANCES AS
(
    SELECT FACT_AS_BALANCE.BALANCE_DATE_ID
    FROM FACT_AS_BALANCE 
      JOIN DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS ON FACT_AS_BALANCE.BALANCE_TYPE_ID = DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS.ID 
    WHERE DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS.TRANSACTION_INTRADAY_FLAG = 'N'
      AND DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS.BALANCE_CLOSING_FLAG = 'Y'
)
SELECT DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, DD.CAL_YEAR, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT FPP.ID),0) AS PAYMENTS, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.ACCOUNT_STATEMENT_ID),0) AS STATEMENTS
FROM FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
  FULL OUTER JOIN FILTERED_BALANCES FAB ON FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID = FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID
  JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID OR FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID = DD.ID 
GROUP BY DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

Have a look at Oracles aggregate functions:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions060.htm#SQLRF00633

Maybe that could help you.

You could anyhow replace your full outer join with a subselect but I don't think that gives much difference.